# TextBox Error Decimal Value insert button to database

Tags: c#

//this button use to save in database. i got this error on my textbox0.Text which is decimal value.

"System.ArgumentException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <> in P_AMOUNT Column.  Expected type is Decimal."

```
 private void butSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

 using (SqlConnection sqlConnection =
             new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-QAB1OL7\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=rosbill;User Id=rosbill;Password=B1@dm1n;"))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                //Add columns  
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CASH_VOUCHER", typeof(string)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DATE", typeof(DateTime)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PAYEE", typeof(string)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("REQUEST_STATUS", typeof(string)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("M_AMOUNT", typeof(decimal)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ITEM", typeof(string)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UNIT", typeof(string)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PRICE", typeof(decimal)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("QTY", typeof(decimal)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CONTRACT_ID", typeof(string)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RECEIVED_BY", typeof(string)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PAYMENT", typeof(string)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PO_NUMBER", typeof(string)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TERMS", typeof(string)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CHECK_NO", typeof(string)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("BANK", typeof(string)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PARTICULARS", typeof(string)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("P_AMOUNT", typeof(decimal)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("STATUS", typeof(string)));
    
foreach (MaterialExpenseItemTemplate template in this.flowLayoutMaterials.Controls)
                    {
                        dt.Rows.Add(txtcash.Text, dateTimePicker3.Value.Date, txtpayee.Text, cmbrequest.Text, template.amount, template.item, template.unit, template.price, template.qty, lblid.Text,txtreceive.Text, cmbpayment.Text, txtpo.Text, cmbterms.Text, txtcheck.Text,txtbank.Text, txtparticulars.Text,txtamount0.Text, cmbstatus.Text);
                    }

                //sqlcon as SqlConnection  
                SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand("insertmaterialexpense", sqlConnection);
                sqlcom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tableexpenses", dt);  

                sqlConnection.Open();
                sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }


            MessageBox.Show("Data Save");
            refresh();
            return;



private void txtamount0_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal intAmount = 0;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtamount0.Text))
        {
            
            return;
        }

        else
        {
            txtamount0.Text = intAmount.ToString("C");
        }                  


    }
```

I would like to know what is the problem even though i already declare it as decimal in the txtamount0..

Comment: i recommend you remove from your code example all the extra propertied unrelated to the problem at hand to help us distil the issue

Comment: but essentially the textbox contains a string, so you'll need to parse it/convert it to a decimal before adding it to the Row

Comment: can you elaborate your comment on what specific properties in unreleated in my post? so i can remove it.

Comment: all the columns  that do not cause any issues

Comment: i can see you have 2 decimal columns there-did you do a convert for BOTH?

Comment: im using user control.cs on  M_Amount a dynamic textbox. there's no error on that end it will save in the database.   after i add my P_Amount in the dt column a static textbox. it error

Comment: Your life would be a lot simpler if you switch away from using textboxes for numeric input and use something that can only accept numeric input

Consider changing the txtamount0 to be a NumericUpDown instead, and use the .Value property instead of the Text property - it's already a decimal and the user cannot enter no-value

Answer (score 0):

`txtamount0.Text` must be converted to `decimal`. Something like this: `decimal.Parse(txtamount0.Text)`

Comment: i already try it. still the same error.

Comment: show us your code that does that...

Comment: show us you converted BOTH string values to a `decimal`...

Comment: Please make sure the text, written in `txtamount0.Text` is `decimal`

Comment: my first try.        decimal intAmount = 0;      intAmount = decimal.Parse(txtamount0.Text)

Comment: @ImbaGaming After writing this code: `intAmount = decimal.Parse(txtamount0.Text)`, you must change the line to `..., txtparticulars.Text, intAmount, cmbstatus.Text);`. Did you do so?

Comment: @MohammadMirmostafa this method will error. it will be put does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

This is what exactly you can do:

```
...EventArgs e)
{
    intAmount = decimal.Parse(txtamount0.Text);
    using (SqlConnection...
    
    foreach (MaterialExpenseItemTemplate template in this.flowLayoutMaterials.Controls)
                    {
                        dt.Rows.Add(txtcash.Text, dateTimePicker3.Value.Date, txtpayee.Text, cmbrequest.Text, template.amount, template.item, template.unit, template.price, template.qty, lblid.Text,txtreceive.Text, cmbpayment.Text, txtpo.Text, cmbterms.Text, txtcheck.Text,txtbank.Text, txtparticulars.Text,
intAmount, cmbstatus.Text);
                    }
```

Finally make sure the stored procedure your are calling, accepts `decimal` for **P_AMOUNT** column

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach (MaterialExpenseItemTemplate template in this.flowLayoutMaterials.Controls)
                    {
                        dt.Rows.Add(txtcash.Text, dateTimePicker3.Value.Date, txtpayee.Text, cmbrequest.Text, template.amount, template.item, template.unit, template.price, template.qty, lblid.Text,txtreceive.Text, cmbpayment.Text, txtpo.Text, cmbterms.Text, txtcheck.Text,txtbank.Text, txtparticulars.Text,  (txtamount0.Text=='' ? 0 : txtamount0.Text) , cmbstatus.Text);
                    }

                //sqlcon as SqlConnection  
                SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand("insertmaterialexpense", sqlConnection);
                sqlcom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tableexpenses", dt);  

                sqlConnection.Open();
                sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }


            MessageBox.Show("Data Save");
            refresh();
            return;
```

Try and coerce that pesky old `txtamount0` value to be a number. Don't accept anything other than a number, `txtamount0` will try and feed you crap, just don't take it.

Comment: *`txtamount0` will try and feed you crap* - it'd be the first time I've seen a computer do that to a human; normally it's the other way round

Answer (score 0):

This method looks wrong:

```
private void txtamount0_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal intAmount = 0;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtamount0.Text))
    {

        return;
    }

    else
    {
        txtamount0.Text = intAmount.ToString("C");
    }                  


}
```

"If the value is blank, let it be, otherwise change the value to 0"

If this method is supposed to make your value good to go into the database then it might need some revision. If you plan to store null in the database if the box is blank, you cannot get away with providing an empty string to a datatable as a value for a decimal column

This explodes:

```
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("x", typeof(decimal));
    dt.Rows.Add("");
```

You'll have to inspect the value of the text property and if it's blank set a DBNull instead:

```
..., txtamount0.Text == "" ? DBNull.Value : txtamount0.Text, ...
```

Datatable will convert a numeric string to a decimal for you, but it won't convert empty string to null

Answer (score 0):

I Got it now. and solve the problem

```
   //add project row here
                if (this.checkBox1.Checked)
                {
                    //insert project expense
                    dt.Rows.Add(txtcash.Text, dateTimePicker3.Value.Date, txtpayee.Text, cmbrequest.Text,
                        0, //amount
                        string.Empty,
                        string.Empty,
                        0,
                        0,
                        lblid.Text,
                        txtreceive.Text,
                        cmbpayment.Text,
                        txtpo.Text,
                        cmbterms.Text,
                        txtcheck.Text,
                        txtbank.Text,
                        txtparticulars.Text,
                        this.projectAmount,
                        cmbstatus.Text
                        );
                }



foreach (MaterialExpenseItemTemplate template in this.flowLayoutMaterials.Controls)
                    {
                        dt.Rows.Add(txtcash.Text, dateTimePicker3.Value.Date, txtpayee.Text, cmbrequest.Text, template.amount, template.item, template.unit, template.price, template.qty, lblid.Text,txtreceive.Text, cmbpayment.Text, txtpo.Text, cmbterms.Text, txtcheck.Text,txtbank.Text, txtparticulars.Text,  null , cmbstatus.Text);
                    }

            //sqlcon as SqlConnection  
            SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand("insertmaterialexpense", sqlConnection);
            sqlcom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tableexpenses", dt);  

            sqlConnection.Open();
            sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

private void txtamount0_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtamount0.Text))
            {
                this.projectAmount = 0;
                return;
            }

            decimal _projectAmount = 0;
            bool isDecimal = Decimal.TryParse(txtamount0.Text, out _projectAmount);

            this.projectAmount = isDecimal ? _projectAmount : this.projectAmount;

            if (!isDecimal)
            {
                this.txtamount0.Text = this.projectAmount.ToString();
            }

        }
```